# List image tags in using Azure Container Registry python API

Tags: python, azure, azure-api-management, azure-container-registry

I'm trying list tags for every image in every azure container registry I have.
I can list the tags of an image using azure CLI:
**az acr repository show-tags --repository hello-world --name registry_name**

But I can't find a way to do it using their API, which is relatively complicated for no apparent reason.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The related API for the command `az acr repository show-tags` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/tag/getlist). Here is the example via the Postman:

[image]

Comment: Does this work for accounts with multi-factor authentication?

Comment: @MehdiKhlifi I'm afraid not, it just uses the username and password of the ACR, not the user account.